# Sphinx copy html file

Tags: html, copy, python-sphinx

I use Sphinx for generate docs and some of docs are pure html files. 
I would like sphinx copy such files to build directory to corresponding path as is.
Can I do it ?

Comment: Maybe the [download](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-download) role is what you are looking for.

Comment: No I i don't want do anything in documentation files, only in config. And it difficult to write roles for all html files. But thanks for reply.

Comment: Ok, what about [html_extra_path](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html?highlight=static#confval-html_extra_path)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I got what you are trying to do.

What I needed was: after creating the html content with sphinx

```
$ make html
```

I needed to copy those html to the doc folder, so github pages would see it.

That said, what I am doing is: I've created a python script to call sphinx and then to copy the files.

The script and the docs are on the folder doc_src. The structure is:

```
Project/
 doc/ (where I need my html)
 doc_src/ (where I build them)
```

The script inside doc_src is something like:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil

def make_doc():
    """Run Sphinx to build the doc."""
    try:
        # removing previous build
        print('removing previous build')
        cmd = 'make clean'
        os.system(cmd)
        shutil.rmtree('../doc/', ignore_errors=True)

        # new build
        cmd = 'make html'
        os.system(cmd)

        # copy files - windows cmd here
        print('copy files')
        cmd = r'xcopy _build\html\. ..\doc\ /e /Y'
        os.system(cmd)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_doc()
```